# why process dont terminate in multiprocess

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

Yesterday i dealt with a log file with about 20 million rows using multiprocessing in python.

1. Start a process named 'producer' to read the file line by line and put it into a queue.
2. Start three processes named 'consumer i' to fetch one line from the queue and analyze it to get the ip.
3. In the main function, i start these processes and wait with join().

Code is below

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty
import os
import time    


def put_ip(src, q, number):
    """ 
    read file line by line, and put it to queue
    """
    print "start put_ip: %d" % os.getpid()
    with open(src) as f:
        for line in f:
            q.put(line)
        for i in range(number):
            q.put(EOFError)
    print "stop put_ip"


def get_ip(lock, src, result, index):
    """ 
    fetch line, and extract ip from it
    """
    print "start get_ip %d: %d" % (index, os.getpid())
    ips = []
    while True:
        line = src.get()
        if line == EOFError:
            print "%d get EOFError" % index
            break
        else:
            res = json.loads(line.strip())
            # process res, get ip
            ips.append(ip)
    print "get_ip %d get %d ips" % (os.getpid(), len(ips))
    result.put('\n'.join(ips))
    ips = []
    print "stop get_ip %d" % os.getpid()
    return


def test_get_ip(src, dest, number):
    """ 
    test with single process
    """
    srcq = Queue()
    result = Queue()

    with open(src) as f:
        for line in f:
            # if 'error' not in line:
            srcq.put(line)
        for i in range(number):
            srcq.put(EOFError)

    get_ip(srcq, result, 0)


def main(src, dest, number):
    """ 
    with multiprocess
    """
    srcq = Queue()
    result = Queue()

    producer = Process(target=put_ip, args=(src, srcq, number))

    consumers = [Process(target=get_ip, args=(srcq, result, i)) for i in xrange(number)]

    print 'start at %s' % time.asctime()
    starttime = time.time()

    producer.start()
    for consumer in consumers:
        consumer.start()

    producer.join()
    for consumer in consumers:
        consumer.join()

    with open(dest, 'w') as w:
        while True:
            try:
                res = result.get_nowait()
                w.write(res +'\n')
            except Empty:
                print 'Empty'
                break

    print "time: %f" % (time.time()-starttime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', dest='src', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-o', dest='dest', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-n', dest='number', type=int, default=2)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.src, args.dest, args.number)
    # test_get_ip(args.src, args.dest, args.number)
```

**The result is strange that consumer process will not terminate after work done, and the main function is blocked at join().**

Test with different suitations and recodes below:

- use **test_get_ip() without multiprocessing** to process small or large log file, it works well.
- use **main() with multiprocessing** to process large log file, it will block at join(). each get_ip process will print "stop get_ip XXXX", but not terminate.
- use **main() to process smaller log file** with 2,000 rows, it works well too. the get_ip will terminate.
- if i **don't store ip in list ips in get_ip()**, it works fine, with small or large log file.

So, what's the problem? Does it have a limitation in list? Is there anything i missed?

My machine environment is:

```
Linux 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
```

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are buffering all the data and send the result only when the consumers are done.

Let's say that the process running `get_ip()` has gathered 1M ip addresses in a list. Now, before termination it needs to *serialize* all this data and pass it through the `Queue`, and then the `main()` function will receive and *deserialize* all that data.

My suggestion is that you put the IP-addresses into the result Queue directly, and then have the `main()` process fetch them and write them as they come.

Comment: as you see, at the end of get_ip(), i add a debug print, **print "stop get_ip %d" % os.getpid()**. it will show at the output. I think **result.put** is finished. Right? But why the get_ip process dont terminate?

Comment: Might be that they won't terminate until the results have been read from the queue.

Comment: But why with smaller log file, it will terminate? The results are read after all consumer processes terminated.